# What Sans Serif font is this?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I've been looking for a day and a half on TypeKit and MyFonts and still can't find the one true font love.

The font I'm looking for is in the header of the image, as I think this font is the same for the entire text.

[image]

Here is what I know about the font:

- The upper-case 'G' has no bar.
- Font is a sans serif.
- It's not Proxima Nova, Gotham, or Helvetica Neue.

I tried to use online tools to find fonts such as:

- [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
- [Linotype Font identifier](https://www.linotype.com/fontidentifier.html)

But I didn't find what I was looking for. I found one similar but not what I was looking for, which was Acherus Grotesque.

If you guys know this font or might know how I can find it, would mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
**Montserrat Font**
[image: Montserrat Hairline]

Im pretty sure this is the font used in what you posted.

Comment: wow I feel so stupid I didn't think to go look at Montserrat you have saved me from my millions of font tabs on my browser,  Thankyou so much @CzarinaBasa much appreciated.

Comment: That looks like it, for sure for sure.